# Table of uni courses, template not optimale for a standing A4 page

Tags: tables, nicematrix

I need to submit a self-assessment of my prior courses in my master's application. I have used a template I like, but I can't manage to make in optimal for a standing A4 page. Furthermore, I have added a column, however, the text won't is centered left and not right as the other columns.

Would appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[textwidth=25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{lllrrr} \toprule \toprule
            \parbox[t]{5cm}{\textbf{Admission requirements \\ for Economics (MSc)}}  & \parbox[t]{4cm}{\textbf{Courses completed}} & \parbox[t]{2cm}{\textbf{Date of \\ completion}} & \textbf{Credits} & \textbf{ECTS} & \parbox[t]{3.8 cm}{\textbf{Degree \\ program}} \\ \midrule
            
            Microeconomics (30 ECTS) & Microeconomics 1  & 22.11.2019  & 6.67& 10  & B.A. Economics, UiO \\
            ~ & Welfare Economics & 15.02.2013 & 8 & 12 & B.A Economics, SDU  \\
            ~ & Strategy and Markets & 01.07.2015 & 10 & 15   & B.A. Economics, SDU \\ 
            ~ & Behavioral Economics & 01.07.2015 & 10 & 15   & B.A. Economics, SDU \\ \midrule
            
            Macroeconomics (30 ECTS) & Macroeconomics 1  & 22.04.2014& 5& 7.5  & B.A. Economics, UiO \\
            ~ & Macroeconomics 2 & 15.02.2013 & 8 & 12 & B.A. Economics, SDU \\ \midrule
            
            Mathematics (30 ECTS) & Mathematics I  & 22.04.2014& 5& 7.5  & B.A. Economics, UiO \\ \midrule
            
            Statistics (30 ECTS) & Statistics 1  & 22.04.2014& 5& 7.5  & B.A. Economics, UiO \\
            ~ & Regression Analysis & 15.02.2013 & 8 & 12 & B.A. Economics, SDU  \\ \midrule \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The table can be made to fit with some rearrangement of the headings.

Instead of `\parbox`, the `\Block` command from the `nicematrix` package was used, which allows not only using `\\` inside but also vertically centering its content across multiple rows. (Useful for the first column).

It is the **only** new command you need to learn.

`\Block{4-1}{Microeconomics \\ (30 ECTS)}` makes a vertically centered  cell of 4 rows x 1 column nicely aligned with the four rows of the next columns.

`\Block{}<\bfseries>{Admission \\requirements \\ for Economics \\(MSc)}` injects `\bfseries` into the four lines cell.

As you can see, the header line has all cells centered vertically.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, multirow}

\usepackage{nicematrix}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llcccc@{}}
        \toprule \toprule
        \Block{}<\bfseries>{Admission \\requirements \\ for Economics \\(MSc)}  &
        \Block{}<\bfseries>{Courses \\ completed}                               &
        \Block{}<\bfseries>{Date of \\ completion}                              &
        \textbf{Credits} & \textbf{ECTS}                                        & 
        \Block{}<\bfseries>{Degree  program \\ (B.A. Economics) }                                       \\ \midrule
    
        \Block{4-1}{Microeconomics \\ (30 ECTS)}& Microeconomics 1      & 22.11.2019 & 6.67 & 10 &  UiO \\
                                                & Welfare Economics     & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12 &  SDU \\
                                                & Strategy and Markets  & 01.07.2015 & 10   & 15 &  SDU \\ 
                                                & Behavioral Economics  & 01.07.2015 & 10   & 15 &  SDU \\ \midrule
        
        \Block{2-1}{Macroeconomics \\(30 ECTS)} & Macroeconomics 1      & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5&  UiO \\
                                                & Macroeconomics 2      & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12 &  SDU \\ \midrule
        
        \Block{}{Mathematics \\(30 ECTS)}       & Mathematics I         & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5&  UiO \\ \midrule
        
        \Block{2-1}{Statistics \\ (30 ECTS)}    & Statistics 1          & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5&  UiO \\
                                                & Regression Analysis   & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12 &  SDU \\ 
        \midrule \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx, varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} X[1, l, m] 
                            X[l, m]
                            X[0.6, c]
                       *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=2.1}]}
                            X[c]
                       @{}},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries, f},
             measure = vbox
              }  
    \toprule[2pt]             
Admission requirements for Economics (MSc)
    &   {Courses\\ completed}
        &   Date of completion
            &   {{{Credits}}}
                &   {{{ECTS}}}
                    &   {Degree program\\ (B.A. Economics)}     \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=4]{m}    {Microeconomics\\(30 ECTS)} 
    & Microeconomics 1      & 22.11.2019 & 6.67 & 10  & UiO  \\
    & Welfare Economics     & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12  & SDU  \\
    & Strategy and Markets  & 01.07.2015 & 10   & 15  & SDU  \\
    & Behavioral Economics  & 01.07.2015 & 10   & 15  & SDU  \\ \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{m}    {Macroeconomics\\ (30 ECTS)} 
    & Macroeconomics 1      & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5 & UiO  \\
    & Macroeconomics 2      & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12  & SDU  \\ 
    \midrule
{Mathematics\\ (30 ECTS)}
    & Mathematics I         & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5 & UiO  \\ 
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=2]{m}    {Statistics\\ (30 ECTS)} 
    & Statistics 1          & 22.04.2014 & 5    & 7.5 & UiO  \\
    & Regression Analysis   & 15.02.2013 & 8    & 12  & SDU  \\
    \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much!

Comment: @SivertDahle, you are welcome. BTW, now is (probably) a time to consider to accept one of  obtained answers (by clicking on check mark at top left side of selected answer). As I see, so far you not accept any of received answers on your questions. Did neither of them deserved this?